# How to structure dataset to run Binomial GLM of ratio of counts over time?

Tags: r

I am trying to do an analysis using a binomial GLM to test for differences in relative count frequency over time (Days). The  GLM model/formula would look something like this:

(1:2) ∼  Day

Where we are testing for the effect of **Day** on the frequency of A1:A2. Basically this is a binomial generalized linear model where A1 and A2 refer to the read counts of alternative alleles at each gene and Day is a multilevel factor. The other thing is that I would be testing this on many different genes (100's) so that we would be doing many tests.

The basic model formula in R is straightforward (e.g. using a long format dataset): `

```
glm(AF1:AF2 ~ Day, data = dfLong, family = "binomial")
```

But Im not really sure how to structure the data or loop over the **Gene** variable to accomplish this task?

Here is an example dataframe:

```
> df<-read.csv("test.csv")
> df
  Gene A.count_1 A.count_2 Day
1    1        60        40   1
2    2       100        30   1
3    3       100         3   1
4    1        55       100   3
5    2       423       410   3
6    3       191        89   3
7    1        20        10   5
8    2       200        10   5
9    3       100        20   5
```

The output I'd like is the test of the effect of **Day** as a factor (not a numeric variable) on allele count ratios for each gene, producing a p-value for each gene (e.g. 1,2, and 3, or more, 100s, in the general case).

Any help to set me in the right direction would be mnuch appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand `glm(AF1:AF2 ~ Day, data = dfLong, family = "binomial")` . If you write `AF1:AF2` as y input, you are giving the function an array longer than Day: `"Error in model.frame.default(formula = AF1:AF2 ~ Day, data = df,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Day')"`

Comment: Thanks for looking at this RobertoT. What I am trying to do is to compare the ratio of counts in the columns `A.count_1` `A.count_2` for each gene, testing the effect of day (as a factor).

Comment: Yeah, but if you write AF1:AF2 what happen to me is like you are saying "create y = a numeric int array 60:40" . At least that is what happen to me and why I get the Error I wrote above. Maybe I'm using wrong the function?

Comment: Honestly, Im not sure what the right function is...I am trying to determine if the ratio of allele counts changes with day - that is the goal. The ratio AF1:AF2 (A.count_1: A.count_2) for each gene/day combination in my example dataset `df` , would be  60:40 (gene 1, day1), 100:30 (gene 2, day1) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that

```r
library('lme4')
m <- lmList(cbind(A.count_1,A.count_2) ~ Day | Gene, data = dfLong, 
            family = "binomial")
summary(m)
```

should probably do it? (From `?binomial`, a two-column matrix response is treated as {number of successes, number of failures})

This works, for some built-in data that comes with the `lme4` package:

```r
lmList(cbind(incidence, size-incidence) ~ period | herd,
      data = cbpp, family = binomial)
```

Comment: Thanks. from my example dataset `df`, which doesnt have ***AF1*** or ***AF2*** variables, would I  simply create the ratio of alleles from my columns `A.count_1` and `A.count2` ? i.e.  `lmList(A.count1:A.count.2 ~ Day | Gene, data=df,family="binomial")`?

Comment: does the variable `AF1:AF2` or whatever variable we are testing against `Day` need to be integral? Does it need to be counts (successes and failures)? How to implement?  I get warnings like this when I put in just the ratio: `In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!`

Comment: This does what I think I want it to do? :  `m <- lmList(cbind(A.count_1,A.count_2) ~ Day | Gene, data = df3, family = "binomial")` - @Ben Bolker - I assume this is considering column 1 of the `cbind` as successes and column 2 as the failures?

Comment: yes, that's right (I didn't read your initial question carefully enough)